# How to check the actual code written for built-in functions in JavaScript? For Example: toUpperCase() or toLowerCase()

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, v8

Am I able to check out the actual code logic, which Javascript is using in its built-in functions like `String.prototype.length()` or `toUpperCase()` or `toLowerCase()` functions? I was searching, but not getting any relevant document showing the actual code defining the logic behind it.

Comment: Well, the v8 engine's sourcecode can be found here: https://github.com/v8/v8. Dunno where to find those specific functions.

Answer (score 2):

You'll have to read the respective engine's source code. Note that engines can and do use a variety of implementation techniques for built-in functions: sometimes they use internal (pseudo-) JavaScript, or they use C/C++ (or whatever language the engine is written in), or (for particularly performance-sensitive things) they might use advanced techniques like hand-written assembly, or custom DSLs or assembly generators, or specialized "lowering" code in their compilers, etc. For many built-in functions, many engines also have more than one implementation, such as a highly optimized but somewhat narrow fast path for the most common cases, and a slower fallback with full spec-compliant functionality for all other cases.

In the specific case of `toUpperCase` in V8, the meat of the implementation is [here](https://source.chromium.org/chromium/chromium/src/+/main:v8/src/objects/intl-objects.cc?q=Intl::ConvertToUpper&ss=chromium%2Fchromium%2Fsrc). (If that link ever becomes stale: search for "ToUpperCase" across the entire source and you're bound to find it somewhere.)

Comment: For Firefox, we can look at SpiderMonkey source code. Currently these functions appear to be defined in /js/src/builtin/String.cpp and the latest tip version of this file can be found at https://hg.mozilla.org/releases/mozilla-release/file/tip/js/src/builtin/String.cpp